# Counting the number of property of class jquery

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like that:

```
<style>
.hello {background:#ccc}
</style>
<div class="hello" style="height:40px; width:60px; display:inline-block">something</div>
```

Currently, class hello has 4 properties (background, height, width, display) but how can I count the number of property of class by jquery?

Thank you so much.

Comment: "_...class hello has three properties..._" Which properties are you talking about?  `height`, `width` and `display` from the `styles´ attribute?

Comment: Hi Andreas. Yes. That is what i am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.attr()` , `String.prototype.split()` with parameter `";"` to retrieve `style` attribute properties set ; utilizing `.text()` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\n|\s+/g` , `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `\.hello\{.*\}/` , `String.split()` with `RegExp` `/\.hello\{|\}|;/` , `Array.prototype.filter()` with parameter `Boolean` to retrieve properties set at `style` element for `.hello` , `Array.prototype.push()` to push properties at `style` element to `props` array

```js
var props = $(".hello").attr("style").split(";");

props.push.apply(props, 
                 $("style").text()
                 .replace(/\n|\s+/g, "")
                 .match(/\.hello\{.*\}/)[0]
                 .split(/\.hello\{|\}|;/)
                 .filter(Boolean)
                );

console.log(props, props.length);
```

```css
.hello {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="hello" style="height:40px; width:60px; display:inline-block">something</div>
```

Comment: Hi. it is great but if I add new property to class .hello like this .hello {background:#ccc} then it's length has total 4 properties then we cannot count it?

Comment: It is great. thank you for your helps with very detailed explanation.